# how to split screen width with spaces

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I need to create 3 blocks with spaces between them.

http://i47.tinypic.com/huos40.png

I have almost done, but I have tried many properties and I don't know what else can I check.

This is my current code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_numbers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_numbers"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_numbers"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cuadrogris"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cuadrogris"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cuadrogris"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I have properly split the width screen by 3, but how can I add that extra space?

Comment: tried adding margin left right to the TextViews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing fantastic

Just Add this to your each **TextView**

```
android:layout_margin="20dp"
```

and see the result. Rest You can fix according to your need

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/ll_numbers"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_numbers"
android:layout_below="@+id/tv_numbers"
android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cuadrogris"
    android:textSize="8sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cuadrogris"
    android:textSize="8sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
     android:background="@drawable/cuadrogris"
    android:textSize="8sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line to each textviews

```
android:layout_margin="10dp"
```

or

as per your requirement

```
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
```